# How to generate a hibernate ID with auto generate with a starting value

Tags: database, hibernate, annotations, setter, auto-generate

Hi I have written code like this

> ```
> @Id
> @Column(nullable=false)
> @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
> public int getUserID() {
>     return UserID; 
> }
> ```

But I manually setting it from DAO like "e.setUserID(01);" to insert.Otherwise row not inserting Is there any process to get value to id and retrieve what value generated automatically. Im thinking i will get some help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
@GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
```

Comment: It worked ,but it is assigning to another column the generated value

Comment: If anyone is down voting, there should be a reason which should be shared, Why down voted?

Comment: This is not a safe method since the generator selects the max id from the db and increments it. Though it is useful for testing purposes. The docs clearly warn `Do not use in a cluster!`. Check it out: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/id/IncrementGenerator.html https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

Comment: @ Bahattin Ungormus did you really read the problem statement ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the IDENTITY generation type instead of auto. Use a Long for id. I also recommend changing the name from ***UserID*** to ***userId***. Do not forget the @Entity for the class name.

```
@Entity
public class MyClass{

private Long userId;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column
    public Long getUserID(){
        return userId;
    }

    //.. rest of class

}
```

Be very careful with the naming conventions and make sure your field names and types match the field names and types from the database.

Comment: It will automatically create ID value when row created...or we should call setter In methods

Comment: You should **never** set an id manually if in the database the id appears as an identity. First make sure that your database configuration is in such a way that it auto-increments the ids. Then map the id column as I suggested above. Again, be careful at naming conventions and types of the data.