# hibernate @Id @GeneratedValue with non auto-increment and i dont have sequence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

i have situation on which i try to persist entity with id that depends on the max id value, for example the new entity id will be MAX(id)+1.
now i try to use JPA to persist this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
```

i used `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO`, `strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY`,`strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE`,`strategy = GenerationType.TABLE` none of them work, so i think i can solve it through selecting the max id then +1 and use that value (i did not try it) what i am asking for, is there is any way to handle this situation through JPA or Hibernate.**Note:the id columns is not auto-increment and the db doesn't have sequence.**

Comment: it doesn't work because its a String. if you use a Long, the `GenerationType.AUTO` should work fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100970/how-to-generate-a-hibernate-id-with-auto-generate-with-a-starting-value

Comment: @XtremeBaumer did not work

Comment: Maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Don't use String as Primary key. if you need id like "ABC123" then take 2 id columns. One as id(int) PK, second as display_id(String). You can auto-generate display_id in database level using trigger.

Comment: Please understand the issue. How can you get Max(id) if you will take id as String ?

Comment: i understand the issue, i don't want use Max(id), that is how the SQL is written by another one. i try to figure out solution.i already made the Id as long and strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, did not work

Answer (score 1):

If you use `String` as a type of your Id you shouldn't use auto-increment cause String is something that can't be incremented since it's not a number type. Just leave `@Id`and add `@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")` - that should work.
Additionally you can add `@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")`